# Automatically generate class skeleton from script

Tags: c++, c, class, dependencies, protocol-buffers

Is there a way to generate C++ classes automatically from a script (like protocol buffers does) but without any external dependencies (unlike protocol buffers)?

The idea is to use a similar script to *.proto* to generate the corresponding class that will only denpend on standard C++. Serialization and parsing does not really matter as much as the structure ease of maintability and evolution.

Comment: Yes, there is a way..

Comment: You can create a C++ program that will convert your script to C++ classes. But that is pretty much what Protocol Buffers does also, just that it happens to use a few extra libraries to do it.